# Are the new vulnerabilities found in Chrome also in Edge?

Tags: google-chrome, security, microsoft-edge

Recently, [Chrome received security patches for severe vulnerabilities](https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-chrome-security-update-fixes-high-risk-flaws/). One of the vulnerabilities  was with Guest View (CVE-2022-2477), and the details of the other (CVE-2022-2480) won't be given out until users have patched Chrome.

Microsoft Edge [is based on Chromium](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2020/01/15/new-year-new-browser-the-new-microsoft-edge-is-out-of-preview-and-now-available-for-download/) and also has a Guest Mode. Would the two security vulnerabilities also effect Edge? Should users of Edge expect Microsoft to roll out security updates?

Comment: The question is too broad - there is not one rule for all bugs, and each bug may have a different route into the final product (or none).

Comment: “Should users of Edge expect Microsoft to roll out security updates?” Ask Microsoft. Seriously, here is their [forum for Edge](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-edge-insider/ct-p/MicrosoftEdgeInsider). They would know more than us.

Comment: In both of those cases the vulnerability exists within Chromium itself not Google Chrome. Microsoft already patched both vulnerabilities within Edge on July 22nd 2022.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where the flaw is.
If the flaw is in the page rendering engine itself (and it usually is), then it will be common for all Chromium-based browsers.
If the flaw is in some Chrome-specific feature that is not present in other Chromium-based browsers, then it affects only Chrome.

In the case you mentioned, I don't know if Guest Mode is a feature present also in other Chromium-based browsers (like MS Edge) or is it Chrome-specific. The other flaw mentioned in the article you linked, related to service worker API, is definitely in the rendering engine, so probably will affect all Chromium-based browsers.

So yes, you can expect that Microsoft will roll out security updates.

Comment: "I don't know if Guest Mode is a feature present also in other Chromium-based browsers (like MS Edge) or is it Chrome-specific." - The article mentions Guest View, and when I did a search, the pages returned for Guest View talked about Guest Mode for Edge.

Comment: @ThaDopestCoder - I addressed that question in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Microsoft Edge is based on Chromium and also has a Guest Mode. Would the two security vulnerabilities also affect Edge?

Microsoft has already documented and patched both vulnerabilities.

- [CVE-2022-2480](https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2022-2480)
- [CVE-2022-2477](https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2022-2477)

> Should users of Edge expect Microsoft to roll out security updates?

Microsoft released an update to address these vulnerabilities within Microsoft Edge on July 22nd, 2022.  Microsoft Edge 103.0.1264.71 and newer isn't vulnerable to the vulnerabilities you listed.